# CSS not loading for some reason

Tags: php, css, apache

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48d7c2e207.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/newsfeed_header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/newsfeedprofile.css">
    <title>News Feed Profile | My Family Gathering</title>
</head>
```

When I go to all my web pages, everything is fine. Such as localhost/website/profile. All the content loads and everything is styled. But when I go to localhost/website/profile/12345, the content loads but there is no styles. Weird enough, when I go to localhost/website/profile.php?id=12345 , everything loads properly. Can someone lead me into the right direction on what to do?

Comment: Can you show me your html? please?

Comment: Sounds like your CSS is being loaded relative to the current URL. View the source of `localhost/website/profile/12345`, and check the URL of the the CSS file

Comment: @mulquin 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48d7c2e207.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/newsfeed_header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/newsfeedprofile.css">
    <title>Website Name</title>
</head>

Comment: Yes it does appear that your CSS is being loaded relative, remove the dot/period before /css and it should work

Comment: @mulquin I removed the ./ in the front and still have the same issue.

Comment: @justRyan Yes I just noticed my error, my mistake. The URLs need to be `/website/css/blah.css`

Comment: @mulquin okay so now my css is linked to ../website/css/newsfeedprofile.css but still not getting anything. DevTools also doesn't show any CSS files linked.

Comment: @mulquin okay so what you said fixed it. I removed the .. from the beginning and it worked. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding type prop:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/newsfeed_header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/newsfeedprofile.css">
```

Comment: And the dot before the path if still does not work.

Comment: I added the full directory /project/website/css/file.css and it worked that way. Thanks for the help though!